# Becoming invisible on the network

Tags: vpn

While I am using Ubuntu, I would like to be invisible on the network. I was told that if I use a VPN that I am completely invisible on the network and no one can find me since I am using the VPN's servers and tunnels.

If I am using a VPN, is it true that I would be invisible on the network when using wifi in a public place as well as at home with my wireless connection?

Comment: Good article at http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/understanding-vpns-how-vpns-can-be-used-for-anonymization shows you must configure the machine with VPN to VPN-encrypt ALL data else your activity can be seen on the local network - or did you mean to write 'Internet' above where you wrote 'network'?

Comment: You have an ip address, thus can always be found, it is only a matter of how difficult. You can be found outside of ip address. See the TOR documentation. Encryption is not the same as being "invisible".

Comment: If you are requesting data that is not on your computer, your computer has to send out signals to request it. Therefore, some one will always be able to tell that your computer is sending out signals, regardless of software.

Comment: Define "invisible".

Answer (score 1):

You won´t be invisible, you will hide under a different IP address that is not yours.

For example, I live in Spain, I can connect a VPN in the US to adquire the IP address and watch Netflix that is not available in my country because I adquire a US IP address and it recognises I´m in the US and not in Spain.

You need to install openVPN:

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn bridge-utils
```

You will then need to find a cheap VPN provider. Just google for it there are many.

Comment: Please learn to format your answer, check the help section for more information. Also why should I only use the cheapest VPN provider? shouldn't I take the one that fit my needs the best? Like anonymity or getting a different IP. those aren't necessarily the same.

Comment: Sometimes good is better than cheap. If you are buyinig privacy, then choosing a VPN provider who guards your privacy is useful. The security.stackexchange.com link above shows a link to an analysis of multiple VPN providers and how well they protect your privacy. Recommended.

Comment: Because if it not used for gaming you dont need a dedicated IP for you and you can take the cheapest alternative out there.

Answer (score 1):

VPN provides secure access to your VPN server's internal network, cloud or anything. For instance you can set a tunnel between your laptop and server and access the Internet using your VPN server's connection and it's IP address which makes your own PC "invisible".

It may help: http://www.pcworld.com/article/223044/vpns_for_beginners_to_experts.html

Consider buying a personal VPN or using the one you may have at work/home. Those "free" VPN's advertised on web provide nothing but a lot of delay and low bandwidth.

For a free solution you may check OpenVNC @ http://openvpn.net